# pointer to a pointer in Delphi

Tags: c++, delphi, pointers

How Can I Write This Code ( C++ : Pointer to Pointer ) In Delphi ?

```
   int  var;
   int  *ptr;
   int  **pptr;

   var = 3000;
   ptr = &var;
   pptr = &ptr;

   cout << "Value of var :" << var << endl;
   cout << "Value available at *ptr :" << *ptr << endl;
   cout << "Value available at **pptr :" << **pptr << endl;
```

Comment: I don't speak a lot of Pascal, but after reading [the first google hit](http://delphi.about.com/od/objectpascalide/a/pointers.htm), I'm pretty confident how I would translate this. What have **you** tried so far?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can do like this

```
var
  i: Integer;
  pi: PInteger;       // or ^Integer
  ppi: ^PInteger;     // or PPInteger, if you first define `type PPInteger = ^PInteger`
begin

  i := 3000;
  pi := @i;
  ppi := @pi;

  Writeln('Value of i: ', i);
  Writeln('Value of i: ', pi^);
  Writeln('Value of i: ', ppi^^);
```

Comment: (I'm not at home at the moment. On my laptop, I only got FPC/Lazarus. I would like to test the above code, but Lazarus refuses to compile anything (even though it is a fresh installation)...)

Comment: @David: Are you sure `^^Integer` compiles? (If not, you'd have to use `^PInteger`.)

Comment: @David: The more I think about it, the more I believe you cannot actually write `^^Sth`... But please correct me (if you got a working compiler to play with!).

Comment: @TLama: Thanks for confirming that.

Comment: @David: TLama confirmed that you cannot write `^^Sth` in Delphi 2009. But then he removed his comment. I don't know why.

Comment: @Andreas: TLama probably removed his comment since it become obsolete after you edited it into your answer.

Answer (score -2):

Code below works fine:

```
program Project1;

{$APPTYPE CONSOLE}

type
  PIntPtr = ^Integer;
  PInt2Ptr = ^TIntPtr;

var
  pi1: PIntPtr;
  pi2: PInt2Ptr;

begin
  New(pi1);
  try
    New(pi2);
    try
      pi1^ := 1000;
      pi2^ := i1;
      WriteLn(pi2^^);
      Readln;
    finally
      Dispose(pi2);
    end;
  finally
    Dispose(pi1);
  end;
end.
```

Comment: Convention for names would be PInteger and PPInteger

Comment: `i2^:=@i1;` looks suspicious. You're assigning a pointer-to-pointer-to-integer to a pointer-to-integer. Also, if `New(i1)` succeeds, and `New(i2)` fails, you don't call `Dispose(i1)`. Given that exception handling is not part of the question, perhaps it would be better to rewrite your answer in a way that avoids the need for it.

Comment: -1: Testing shows it really does output garbage because of that.

Comment: I fixed your code for you. If you ran your compiler in a mode where the `@` operator returned a typed pointer rather than an untyped `Pointer`, then the compiler would have rejected your code.

Comment: @AndreasRejbrand They say that he who would pun would pick a pocket, but you get +1 from me.